# Project Missing in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics, axapta

Recently, we made some changes to our **Enterprise Portal** project in AX.  To deploy it, we exported the project, afterwards importing it into the new environment.  This is the same procedure we've used numerous times before.

*This time*, however, after the import -- no matter how many times we closed our client, restarted the AOS, or refreshed the project tree, loading the project back up did **NOT** show the changes that were expected from the new project.

It is important to note that the import *worked*, because new objects were added to the AOT.  We tried to rename the project to something like "EPold", and expected that during the next attempt to import the project again, that a new version called "EP" (the old name) would be created.  This **never** happened.

Now we thought that perhaps there was an ID issue with the project. So we *deleted* the EPold project (the only remaining copy of this project) and tried importing again.  Now we're left with no remaining projects relating to the EP.

Does anyone have any other ideas or tricks on how to get imported projects to show back up in the Projects Tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment yet so I will try to be specific.

1) Big imports might need a compilation/sync on the AOT.

2) If you are importing through AOD deployment (yes that means copying the entire layer you are developing into to the other machine) make sure the AOD file has appropriate permissions in the filesystem otherwise AOS won't see it

3) Try to refresh the AOD file from EP (probably you did when you said "refreshed he project tree" just to make sure)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We tried a sync, but that did not appear to have any effect. We were just using the import/export feature from within the AX client in the project window. When you say AOD, are you referring to just moving the physical files between machines?

Comment: Now I can comment!!  were you able to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, we did some other maintenance on the AOSs, and after a copy of the AOS we were able to get it working again. Your suggestions were helpful, and I've put them in my repertoire for future troubleshooting. :)